# Vue .js v-on:input how to pass parameters(inputted value and the index) to a computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, computed-properties

I have two arrays.

1. **items**

   items: [
       ["Malibana", "23", "Vanila"],
       ["Munchee", "34", "Chocalate"],
       ["Little", "23", "Stobery"]
     ]
2. **items2**

   items: [
           ["Malibana", "23", "Vanila"],
           ["Munchee", "34", "Chocalate"],
           ["Little", "23", "Stobery"]
         ]

then I loop **items** array in my component

```
    <ul>
    <li v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
      <input v-on:input="process(index)" type="text">{{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

then some one input a value inside a input field `process computed property` calls to add 3rd element for the **items2** array.

**My question is**
this isn't pass the index. it passes a vue component as well as how to I pass the inputted value to the computed property.

Comment: Don't use computed property in this case. Use a method instead

Comment: I used a method. But I doesn't update the my array

Comment: Could you please add process method here?

Comment: You can not pass arguments in computed property because computed properties are cached and change only when their dependencies change.
You should use method in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $event to pass the inputted value to process and then you can push it to items. Also, I would use v-one:change instead of v-on:input, because v-on:input calls process for every key press and I don't think that is something you want.

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
        <input v-on:change="process($event,index)" type="text">{{item}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And now we can push it

```
methods: {
    process(event, index){
        this.items[index].push(event.target.value);
    }
}
```